# How can I disable double click on Jquery Modal Dialog button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m using Jquery Modal Dialog for submitting some data into the server side and after that saving into database; here my modal dialog code is:

```
    function loadUserDialog(tag, event, target, id) {
            event.preventDefault();

$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#frmModalPopup');

            var $loading = $('<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/ajaxLoading.gif")" alt="loading" class="ui-loading-icon" style="margin: 150px 150px;">');
            var $url = $(tag).attr('href');
            var $title = $(tag).attr('title');
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>');
            $dialog.empty();
            $dialog
            .append($loading)
            .load($url)
              .dialog({
                  autoOpen: false
               , title: $title
               , width: 500
               , modal: true
               , minHeight: 400
               , show: 'fade'
               , hide: 'fade'
              });
            $dialog.dialog("option", "buttons", {
                "Submit": function () {
                    var dlg = $(this);
                    if (IsValidUserName() && $('#frmModalPopup').validate().form()) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: $url,
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: $(target).serialize(),
                            success: function (response) {
                                var cid = $(response).attr('id');
                                if (cid != null && cid != undefined) {
                                    $(response).fadeIn('slow').appendTo(id);
                                    $(window).scrollTop($('#' + cid).offset().top);
                                }

                                dlg.dialog('close');
                                dlg.empty();
                            },
                            error: function (xhr) {
                                alertMessage("EmailId is already in use!");
                                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#frmModalPopup');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    $(this).empty();
                }
            });

            $dialog.dialog('open');
        };
```

But when I do multiple clicks on Submit button at time (more than once) then form is submitted more than once and I got duplicate data submission information. So could you please tell me how to disable double click or more than once click on button Submit.

Comment: all you had were .net and mvc tags. No jquery tag at all!

Comment: How does stop prevent the submit firing twice?

Answer (score 3):

Disable the dialog on first submit, check if it is disabled before proceeding, return if already disabled.

```
"Submit": function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass("disabled"))
    return;

  $(this).addClass("disabled");

  // continue;
}
```

Edit: You can use this approach to add some additional user interface responsiveness, by adding a "Working..." or some other message when you disable it

```
$(this).addClass("disabled");
$dialog.append("Working...");
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery ui has nice function named isOpen().
If dialog is closed but we can see it to prevent next click we can use function isOpen():

```
"Submit": function () {
    if( $(this).dialog("isOpen") ){
        YOUR CODE           
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    $(this).dialog("close");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to disable the button for avoid double click but I need the button came back enabled after and async form submitted.

For this I use a window variable, it's not elegant but functional:

```
function openDialog() {
    window.clickOk = false;
    $("#divAnagrafica").dialog({
      ......
        buttons: [
                {
                    text: "Ok",
                    click: function () {
                        if (window.clickOk === true) {
                            return; 
                        }
                        window.clickOk = true;
                        $("#myForm").submit();
                    }
                },
```

Answer (score -1):

You can disable the pointer-events on the button as soon as the first click happens:

> The `pointer-events` CSS property sets under what circumstances (if
>   any) a particular graphic element can become the target of pointer
>   events

**pointer-events: none** means :

> The element is never the target of pointer events; however, pointer
>   events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have
>   pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances,
>   pointer events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as
>   appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event
>   capture/bubble phases.

```
click: function (e) {
   //your code to open dialogue etc..
   `$`(e.target).css('pointer-events', 'none');
   //your code}
```